# How can I search for all the texts in red in a PDF file?

Tags: windows, pdf

I have a PDF file with mostly black text and some red text. How can I search for all the texts in red? I use Windows.

---

My [PDF file](https://www.cbp.gov/sites/default/files/assets/documents/2023-Aug/Signatory%20VWP%20Carriers%202023-08.pdf) ([mirror](https://ia600501.us.archive.org/7/items/signatory-vwp-carriers/Signatory%20VWP%20Carriers%202023-08.pdf)):

[image]

[...]

[image]

...

Comment: https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-search-a-PDF-file-for-colored-text

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5872051/how-to-get-text-with-a-certain-color-from-a-pdf-c-sharp

Answer (score 1):

The answer would be use MSWord to find where the text is red in the source, since the one and only red text in that PDF is `A carrier is requi`**red** all the other text is 2 shades of outline black true type (by inference a black outer stroke and a black inner fill) which can be then changed to other colours during rendering.

So what you want is where the file says for the following objects (possibly inclusive of black text) stroke and or fill as a colour that has a high red content i.e. you are probably looking for 1 0 0 or similar depending on sources.

One easy method is export the PDF to HTML where a red rendered black text will be much easier to detect by searching words.

**color:#ff0000">BermudAir  (0710/2030)**

For that specific PDF here is the first example as PDF decoded

```
/Span <</MCID 6/Lang(en-US)>> BDC
.00000912 0 612 792 re
W*
n
1 0 0 rg
1 0 0 RG
BT
/F1 12 Tf
1 0 0 1 54.025 643.95 Tm
[(Be)-5.0000007(rmu)-6.0000007(d)-6.0000007(Ai)-6.0000007(r )7.0000007( )7.0000007(\(0)-6.0000007(7)14.000001(1)-6.0000007(0)-6.0000007(/)7.0000007(2)-6.0000007(0)-6.0000007(3)14.000001(0)-6.0000007(\))] TJ
ET
```

Where we clearly see the red as

```
1 0 0 rg
1 0 0 RG
```

and imminently after the letters that are from Begin Text (BT) to End Text (ET) that include enough letters to be decoded and rendered into `BermudAir`

However that chunk of page 6 was heavily encoded and needed decoding to be readable in Notepad.

Decompressing a PDF (cross platforms) is easy in a single line using PDFtk or qpdf or many other PDF tools, what is easy on Linux is find a chunk of text from `1 0 0 rg` or `1 0 0 RG` to `ET` but not so simple in Windows.

### Answer

Much simpler is the PDF2HTML approach with Windows findstr `#ff0000` could be all on one line. We can in a batch file remove the parts before (up to and including) `color:#ff0000">` and also remove  `</span></p>` after the core content

```
mutool convert -F html -o text.htm "Signatory VWP Carriers 2023-08.pdf"

C:\mupdf\1.20.0>findstr /i "color:#ff0000" text.htm

<p style="top:138.4pt;left:54.0pt;line-height:12.0pt"><span style="font-family:Arial,sans-serif;font-size:12.0pt;color:#ff0000">BermudAir  (0710/2030) </span></p>
<p style="top:497.3pt;left:54.0pt;line-height:12.0pt"><span style="font-family:Arial,sans-serif;font-size:12.0pt;color:#ff0000">Challenge Air Cargo, Ltd  (07/10/2030) </span></p>
<p style="top:469.8pt;left:54.0pt;line-height:12.0pt"><span style="font-family:Arial,sans-serif;font-size:12.0pt;color:#ff0000">ES Windows Aviation  (07/10/2030) </span></p>
<p style="top:276.5pt;left:54.0pt;line-height:12.0pt"><span style="font-family:Arial,sans-serif;font-size:12.0pt;color:#ff0000">Kelowna Flightcraft Air Charter dba KF Aeroflyer  (07/10/2030) </span></p>
<p style="top:387.0pt;left:54.0pt;line-height:12.0pt"><span style="font-family:Arial,sans-serif;font-size:12.0pt;color:#ff0000">Normandie Administradora de Bens E Partipacoes LTDA  (07/05/2030)  </span></p>
<p style="top:138.4pt;left:54.0pt;line-height:12.0pt"><span style="font-family:Arial,sans-serif;font-size:12.0pt;color:#ff0000">Royal Company  (07/10/2030)  </span></p>
<p style="top:359.3pt;left:54.0pt;line-height:12.0pt"><span style="font-family:Arial,sans-serif;font-size:12.0pt;color:#ff0000">SLVR Air LLC  (07/07/2030) </span></p>
<p style="top:179.9pt;left:54.0pt;line-height:12.0pt"><span style="font-family:Arial,sans-serif;font-size:12.0pt;color:#ff0000">Stebbins Aviation Inc.  (07/11/2030) </span></p>
<p style="top:138.4pt;left:54.0pt;line-height:12.0pt"><span style="font-family:Arial,sans-serif;font-size:12.0pt;color:#ff0000">Volair Lineas Aereas del Caribe SA LLC  (07/11/2030)  </span></p>
```

[image]

```
@echo off & Title "Searching for red text" & if not [%~x1] == [.pdf] echo I need pdf to re[a]d & pause & exit /b
set "mutool=C:\Users\lez\Downloads\Apps\PDF\mupdf\1.20.0\mutool.exe"

"%mutool%" convert -F html -o"%tmp%\_txt.htm" "%~1%"
findstr /i "color:#ff0000" "%tmp%\_txt.htm">"%tmp%\_txt.txt"
for /f "usebackq tokens=4* delims=#<>" %%a in ("%tmp%\_txt.txt") do echo %%a

REM DECIDE WHAT YOU WANT WITH THE ABOVE OUTPUT
pause>nul
```

Answer (score 0):

On Page #22 of the example in your question, the line in red is when converted to html, it generates the strings in the line below:

```bat
<div class="... baseline;color:rgba(255,0,0,1);">Royal Company (07/10/2030)</span>...;
```

---

[image]

---

Considering that the strings `..rbga(255,0,0,1...` present in the lines are those that correspond to the text targeted for extraction, simply convert your **[`PDF to HTML`](https://www.xpdfreader.com/download.html)** and use a double `For /F` loop to list in **"paged"** order and get the lines in order of occurrence (from first to last) on the resulting files that contain the string for **red color**:

---

**1.** Use **`PDFtoHTML.exe`** to convert **`Input.pdf`** to **`\HTML_DIR\OutPut`**

```bat
2>nul "C:\Full\Path\To\bin\pdftohtml.exe" "C:\Full\Path\To\File\Signatory VWP Carriers 2023-08.pdf" "%temp%\Signatory VWP Carriers 2023-08"
```

**Obs.:** the `2>nul` is just hides the output of messages *font not found* (if a source is not installed on the system), which obviously does not interfere with obtaining a line of interest.

> ```bat
> Config Error: No display font for 'Symbol'
> Config Error: No display font for 'ZapfDingbats'
> ```

---

**2.** Obtain the full path to the `.html` file in a loop (page by page) and extract the line in red in a second loop already filtering the lines of interest with `find`:

```bat
for /f ^usebackq^delims^= %i in (`dir /b /o:d /a:-d "%temp%\Signatory VWP Carriers 2023-08\Page*.html"`)do @for /f ^eol^=^)^usebackq^tokens^=^3^delims^=^<^> %G in (`@find /i "rgba(255" ^< "%temp%\Signatory VWP Carriers 2023-08\%~nxi"`)do @echo/%~G
```

---

**3.** Remove the folder created by the pdf to html conversion:

```bat
2>nul RMDir "%temp%\Signatory VWP Carriers 2023-08" /s /q
```

---

**4.** Remove additional spaces present at the end of each line/output with **[`eol`](https://is.gd/eolforF)**

```bat
for /f "eol=) usebackq ...
```

---

In a bat file it would be:

```bat
@echo off 

set "_pdftohtml=C:\Full\Path\To\bin\pdftohtml.exe"
2>nul RMDir "%temp%\Signatory VWP Carriers 2023-08" /s /q

2>nul "%_pdftohtml%" "C:\Full\Path\To\Signatory VWP Carriers 2023-08.pdf" "%temp%\Signatory VWP Carriers 2023-08"

for /f ^usebackq^delims^= %%i in (`dir /b /o:d /a:-d "%temp%\Signatory VWP Carriers 2023-08\Page*.html"
   `)do for /f ^eol^=^)^usebackq^tokens^=^3^delims^=^<^> %%G in (`find /i "rgba(255" ^< "%temp%\Signatory VWP Carriers 2023-08\%%~nxi"
        `)do echo/%%~G

2>nul RMDir "%temp%\Signatory VWP Carriers 2023-08" /s /q
```

---

The same bat but treating the pdf file by argument or "Drag And Drop"

```bat
@echo off

if not "%~x1" == ".pdf" goto :eOf
set "_pdftohtml=C:\Full\Path\To\bin\pdftohtml.exe"

echo/Stay there!.. I'm working on the file "%~f1"
2>nul =;( RMDir "%temp%\%~n1" /s /q & "%_pdftohtml%" "%~f1" "%temp%\%~n1" );=

for /f ^usebackq^delims^= %%i in =;(`dir /b /o:d /a:-d "%temp%\%~n1"`
    );= do for /f ^eol^=^)^usebackq^ ^tokens^=^3^ ^delims^=^<^> %%G in =;(`
         find /i "rgba(255" ^< "%temp%\%~n1\%%~nxi"`)do echo/%%~G

2>nul RMDir "%temp%\%~n1" /s /q /s /q
```

---

The same as above, but it doesn't print anything, the lines are added to your **[clipboard](https://ss64.com/nt/clip.html)**, paste where necessary:

```bat
@echo off

if not "%~x1" == ".pdf" goto :eOf
set "_pdftohtml=C:\Full\Path\To\bin\pdftohtml.exe"

echo/Stay there!.. I'm working on the file "%~f1"
2>nul =;( RMDir "%temp%\%~n1" /s /q & "%_pdftohtml%" "%~f1" "%temp%\%~n1" );=

=;(@for /f "usebackq delims=" %%i in =;(`
     @dir /b /o:d /a:-d "%temp%\%~n1"
        `);= do @for /f "eol=) usebackq tokens=3 delims=<>" %%G in =;(`
             @find /i "rgba(255" ^^^< "%temp%\%~n1\%%~nxi"
               `);= do @echo/%%~G);=|clip & 2>nul RMDir "%temp%\%~n1" /s /q /s /q
```

---

Getting lines in a text file **`OutPutFile.txt`**:

```bat
@echo off

if not "%~x1" == ".pdf" goto :eOf
set "_pdftohtml=C:\Full\Path\To\bin\pdftohtml.exe"

echo/Stay there!.. I'm working on the file "%~f1"
2>nul =;( RMDir "%temp%\%~n1" /s /q & "%_pdftohtml%" "%~f1" "%temp%\%~n1" );=

=;(@for /f "usebackq delims=" %%i in =;(`
     @dir /b /o:d /a:-d "%temp%\%~n1"
        `);= do @for /f "eol=) usebackq tokens=3 delims=<>" %%G in =;(`
             @find /i "rgba(255" ^< "%temp%\%~n1\%%~nxi"
               `);= do @echo/%%~G);= > "C:\Full\Path\To\OutPutFile.txt"

2>nul RMDir "%temp%\%~n1" /s /q /s /q
```

---

---

**Additional Resources:**

- [`cd /d`](https://ss64.com/nt/cd.html)
- [`if /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)
- [`For /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)
- [`For /F /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)
- [Conditional Execution](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)

  - [`||`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html) and [`&&`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)
- [Commands Redirection](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)

  - `|`, `<`, `>`, `2>`, etc.

- **[`pdftohtml` version 4.04](https://www.xpdfreader.com/download.html)**

- [How does the Windows Command Interpreter [`cmd.exe`] Parse Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4094699/6819406)